# jq JSON display all values on same line

Tags: json, jq, csv

I am sure this is simple, but I have been trying for hours.

I want to display the two values in each object under the appservice array, and list both values per block on one line along with the relevant IP and name.

My JSON is like this:

```
{
  "allow": [
    {
      "name": "username1",
      "scm": "true",
      "ipstart": "192.168.1.2",
      "ipend": "192.168.1.2",
      "cidr": "/32",
      "resources": [
        {
          "appservice": [
            {
              "resourcegroup": "resourcegroup1",
              "resource": "resource1"
            },
            {
              "resourcegroup": "resourcegroup2",
              "resource": "resource2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "sqlserver": [
            {
              "resourcegroup": "resourcegroup3",
              "resource": "resource3"
            },
            {
              "resourcegroup": "resourcegroup4",
              "resource": "resource4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "username2",
...
...
```

and I want to end up like this:

```
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup1 resource1 username1
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup2 resource2 username1

192.168.1.3 resourcegroup5 resource5 username2
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup6 resource6 username2
```

I have tried:

```
jq -r '.allow[] | "\(.ipstart) \(.resources[].appservice[]?.resourcegroup) \(.resources[].appservice[]?.resource) \(.name)"' test.json
```

which must be iterating too many times, as I get double the lines and the "resourcegroup" names are not matching the "resource" names

```
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup1 resource1 username1
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup2 resource1 username1
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup1 resource2 username1
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup2 resource2 username1
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup5 resource5 username2
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup6 resource5 username2
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup5 resource6 username2
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup6 resource6 username2
```

And I tried:

```
jq -r '.allow[] | "\(.ipstart) \(.resources[].appservice[]? | .[])  \(.name)"' test.json
```

which gives me:

```
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup1  username1
192.168.1.2 resource1  username1
192.168.1.2 resourcegroup2  username1
192.168.1.2 resource2  username1
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup5  username2
192.168.1.3 resource5  username2
192.168.1.3 resourcegroup6  username2
192.168.1.3 resource6  username2
```

I tried other combos as well, but the above were the closest.
I could do some sed/awk work to re-parse the jq output, but I'm sure there must be some really simple way via jq to avoid having to re-parse it.

Comment: Where did the `192.168.1.3`s come from?

Answer (score 1):

This simple variation should not have the Cartesian product problem of your attempt. Your mistake seems to be introducing the string interpolation too early.

```
jq -r '.allow[]
       | {ipstart,name} + .resources[].appservice[]?
       | "\(.ipstart) \(.resourcegroup) \(.resource) \(.name)"
' file.json
```

Comment: Fantastic - it was so simple after all - easy once you know how I guess :-)  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a shorter way, but this seems to work:

```
jq -r '.allow[]
       | .ipstart as $ip | .name as $name
       | .resources[].appservice | select(.)
       | .[].name |= $name | .[].ip |= $ip
       | .[] | [.ip, .resourcegroup, .resource, .name]
       | @tsv
' file.json
```

Comment: That is great.  I may have been expecting it to be simpler, hence I never got round to a more "complex" query as you have suggested.  I will endeavour to work through your example to ensure I understand how it works. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want space-separated values (without regard to whether the values contain spaces), you could use `join/1`:

```
jq -r '.allow[]
   | [.ipstart] 
     + (.resources[].appservice[]?
        | [.resourcegroup, .resource]) 
     + [.name]
   | join(" ")
 ' file.json
```